# Not able to send jsp parameters value to action class in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

My jsp file is

```
<s:form action="UpdatePartnerPL" method="post">
        <s:textfield label="PARTNER NAME" readonly="true" disabled="true" id="ptnrname" value="%{ptnrpl.partner_name}" required="true" tooltip="Mandatory Field" name="ptnrpl.partner_name" />
            <s:textfield name="siebel_row_id" readonly="true" disabled="true" label="SIEBEL_ROW_ID"  value="%{ptnrpl.siebel_row_id}"  maxlength = "50"  id="sbl_row_id" />
            <s:checkboxlist label="PRODUCT GROUP" list="prdgrp" name="productgrp" value="%{ptnrpl.product_group}" id="productgrp" required="true" tooltip="Select atleast one or multiple product groups to display Product Lines" onclick ="callprdlines();"/>
            <s:optiontransferselect 
            label="PL LIST"
            name="leftSidePLlist"
            leftTitle="List of available Product Lines"
            rightTitle="Selected Product Lines"
            list="plList"
            id="plListid" 
            headerKey="headerKey"
            headerValue="--- Please Select ---"
            doubleName="plCode" 
            doubleHeaderKey="doubleHeaderKey"
            doubleList="sel_plList"
            doubleHeaderValue="--- Please Select ---"/>
            <s:textfield name="duns_id" label="DUNS ID" readonly="true" disabled="true" value="%{ptnrpl.duns_id}" maxlength = "50"  />
            <s:checkboxlist label="Allow Partner flow to Down Stream"  list="filters" value="%{ptnrpl.ptnr_dwnstrm_filter}" required="true" name="filter"  />
            <sx:datetimepicker  required="true" name="start_date" label="START_DATE"  displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"  value="%{#ptnrpl.start_date}" />
            <sx:datetimepicker name="end_date" required="true" label="END_DATE"   displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"  value="%{#ptnrpl.end_date}" />
            <s:textfield name="comment" label="COMMENT" value="%{ptnrpl.comments}" maxlength = "100"  />
```

In my action i have defined all parameters with their names and also ptnrpl object i am referring but still i am not getting values in action class from jsp
please help

Comment: i am not able to send complete jsp

Comment: Do you submit the form?

Comment: Are you using the default interceptor stack, or a custom one?

Comment: Do you have Setters for your parameters in the Action ?

Comment: Hi Andrea, yes i have all setters and getters but getting null printed when i run the application.

Comment: Please, edit your post by adding your Action code (the relevant part if it is big, and don't forget the getters and setters)

Comment: public String getSiebel_row_id() {
   return siebel_row_id;
  }
public void setSiebel_row_id(String siebel_row_id) {
   this.siebel_row_id = siebel_row_id;
  }
  public String getFilter() {
   return filter;
  }

  public void setFilter(String filter) {
   this.filter = filter;
  }

  public String getDuns_id() {
   return duns_id;
  }

  public void setDuns_id(String duns_id) {
   this.duns_id = duns_id;
  }

  private String siebel_row_id;
  private String partner_name;
  private String filter;
  private String duns_id;

Comment: i have given only 4 fields as im not able to paste the complete file here

Answer (score 0):

add this in the end

```
<s:submit valur="submit">
 </s:form>
```

and put name of the field in JSP page into your JSP page and make getter/setter of all.